# Changing StackEdit Formatting

Tags: stackedit

I am new to StackEdit.  I notice that it adds an underline to H1 elements in the html output.

[image]

Is it possible to change that -- I would like to remove the underline.  If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to Stackedit... Just found an answer to your question, which was also one of my questions. It is possible to remove the underline for h1 and h2, but it's not *very* simple...

Open a published page or preview of a stackedit page in a browser, right-click and choose "page source"

There, in the head, find this line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackedit.io/style.css" />`
Open that address (htps....css) in a browser. Right-click and choose Download.
Open the downloaded file in a text editor or html editor. Use the "search" function to find "h1". It will find "h1:after, h2:after". Remove the words "after" and save.

Next time you've made a new stackedit page it will again have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackedit.io/style.css" />` in its head.

Change this to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" />`, so it points to your local style.css. Your link may be somewhat different. In my case the html page is in the same folder as the folder "styles", which contains the style.css file.

I hope my answer makes sense!
As I am a Stackedit-beginner too, I started writing down my notes and decided to [share](https://stackedit-md.runkodapps.com/index.html) them. It's a work in progress ;)

[EDIT]: an easier way is to just choose another style.css, one you like that does not have the underlines. 
Then adjust your template in the Stackedit editor to point to that css, like so:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` 
to avoid the page is send with the original "underlining style.css" because the original `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackedit.io/style.css" />` would do that.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier just use this in your CSS

```css
h1:after, h2:after {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```